# SQL performance optimization (Entity Framework)

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, performance, sql-server-2008

I am experiencing a really poor performance from Entity Framework.

I am binding it to views, and querying them takes 3-6x longer using EF.

Here is my test case (pseudo), Regular select of the same data:

```
Select * FROM myView 
WHERE DateField > X 
AND DateField < Y AND ID in ('a','b') 
AND [expirationDateTime] = '9999-12-31'

Execution Time: 0:30
```

EF generated SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Field1] AS [Field1], 
    ...
    FROM  (SELECT 
              [myView].Field1 AS [Field1]
              ...
              FROM [dbo].[myView] AS [myView]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[DateField] > @p_linq__0)
    AND   ([Extent1].DateField] < @p_linq__1)
    AND   ([Extent1].[expirationDateTime] = @p__linq__2)',
    N'@p__linq__0 datetime,@p__linq__1 datetime,@p__linq__2 datetime',
      @p__linq__0='2010-12-01 00:00:00',
      @p__linq__1='2011-01-06 00:00:00',
      @p__linq__2='9999-12-31',

Execution Time: 2:54
```

How can EF query be optimized considering that there is limited control over how the SQL is rendered?

Comment: `AND ID in ('a','b')` seams to be missing from the EF version. That might do a big difference.

Comment: @Mikael - that should be an answer.

Comment: I would **never** trust EF to optimize a query. For complicated queries you should always check what it's doing. EF is an ORM, not a query optimizer.

Comment: oops, as i was constructing forum friendly test case pseudo code, i missed a few details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND ID in ('a','b')` seams to be missing from the EF version. That might do a big difference.

Answer (score -1):

did you put WITH (NOLOCK) in all of your views? lol

Comment: NOLOCK can have unexpected consequences - you can miss committed data or get committed data returned more than once. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx